# Move SVN changes to git

Tags: git, github, svn, migration, git-svn

In the company where I work, we are currently in the process of migrating from SVN to git and also updating frameworks and languages version in the process. as a result i currently have 2 repositories, one in svn and another one git which both have received many commits after the initial migration.

Our git repository is GitHub and I used the GitHub migration tool to create the initial commit bringing all the history from svn to the Github repo.

My problem is that I need now to update the GitHub repository with the most recent bug fixes that have been applied to svn. is there any way to sync these 2 repos without doing it manually?

Any help would be appreciated since I'm applying commit by commit manually to the GitHub branch but there are so many changes that this is going to take forever.

My expectation is to be able to merge automatically the svn repo commits (history not needed) to the GitHub branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) to create a git "mirror" of your Subversion repository. Then cherry-pick or merge changes as needed to your branch in GitHub.

Since git-svn operates bi-directionally, you can use the same setup for pushing changes from GitHub into the Subversion repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can try svn2git, I is a tiny utility for migrating projects from Subversion to Git while keeping the trunk, branches and tags where they should be.

Here is the link https://github.com/iteman/svn2git/tree/master

Or you can have a look in this script (It is one way sync from svn to git)
https://gist.github.com/stefanfoulis/909746